# Youtube hanging after a certain amount of time

Tags: google-chrome, caching, youtube, microsoft-edge

Not sure if this is the correct site to ask, tried SuperUser, got no replies.

I've been experiencing this issue for a while, but didn't really bother me until I started using Youtube for music and it hanged after every 2-3 videos.

Basically what happens is if I click on a new video or YT moves onto the next one, the red bar on the top gets stuck at ~75% and just nothing happens. The UI is still interactable but the only fix is reloading the page forcefully. Happened across multiple browsers (Chrome and Edge mainly).

At first I thought this was a networking issue, so I removed my PiHole and uninstalled any virtual network drivers I had (mostly VPNs) and rebooted both my router and my PC. The issue still persisted.

I started checking the Networking tab of inspect element to see what I find, maybe uBlock is blocking something. Well it was blocking something, but it wasn't my issue, as it still persist even if it is disabled. Networking tab with uBlock enabled looks like this:
[image: with ublock enabled]

I thought uBlock was doing something, so I disabled it. The issue went from the requests being blocked, to the requests being stuck on pending:
[image: with ublock disabled]

I tried the URL with an online API tester, and it just returns an empty object on a POST request, but it does return something, meaning something is wrong with my end. The dev tools menu said that a 'Cache-Control' header is missing, so maybe its an issue with caching. I cleared my cache and tried Shift+Refreshing. It worked for seemingly longer after that, but after 10-20 minutes it happened again. Current edge version is 89.0.774.75.

Any help is appreciated and if this is the wrong forum for this, I'll try again on SuperUser maybe I'll get lucky this time.

Here's the URL: https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/log_event?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8

Comment: I didn't meet this issue when I watch videos on YouTube using Edge 89.0.774.77. I suggest that you can update your browser to the latest version and disable all the extensions in the browser and try again. I also find this online that turn off [Use hardware acceleration when available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3leMR.png) will help, you can also try.

Comment: @YuZhou I've already tested it with extensions disabled and just updated edge. I'm gonna try to disable hardware acceleration, will report how it went.

Comment: No, hardware acceleration didn't fix it, it seemingly made it worse, now using Edge 89.0.774.77.

Comment: You say the issue also exists on other browsers, then I think it might be not the browsers' issue. There're many other reasons can cause the issue. Please check your computer to see if there's virus and malware which lead to the issue. Not enough memory, not enough total RAM, video card drivers need updated and so on, these all might be the reasons.

Comment: @YuZhou I checked with Malwarebytes recently, which found no viruses. I have 16 gigabytes of RAM of which at most 7 is used while idle and my GPU (GTX 1060 6G) has up to date drivers.

Comment: Does the issue also occur with other video websites? If it only occurs with youtube, I suggest that you can ask for help on [YouTube Help Community](https://support.google.com/youtube/community?hl=en) and send feedback to youtube.